# How to slove the error: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not build image

Tags: java, apple-m1, dockerfile-maven-plugin

local env：

- JDK：azul-17 17.0.4
- CPU：M1
- system：12.6 (21G115)

When I use the dockerfile-maven-plugin plugin for dockerfile:deploy to build the image, it prompts an error：`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /var/folders/s8/13717jdj3jn4gq6n5y9jh8480000gn/T/jffi7101705819295494870.dylib`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNMVO.png)

There is also no such file in the directory /var/folders/s8/13717jdj3jn4gq6n5y9jh8480000gn/T/：jffi7101705819295494870.dylib：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Wzj.png)

Answer (score 1):

Specific solution reference: arm64 is not supported， Need to replace plugin。
https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/issues/394

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).